# Firebase notification not received in background or when app is closed

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

The app does not receive notification when it is in closed or in the background. Below down is My service class which handles the notification.
The notification is working only when the only app is running.

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFMService";
    Random random = new Random();
    int NOTIFICATION_ID = random.nextInt(9999 - 1000) + 1000;

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        sendNotification();


    }

    private void sendNotification() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationDisplay.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_bouddha_icon)
                .setContentTitle("Bouddha Meridian School")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Comment: how you sending notification console or Server?

Answer (score 0):

Have you download google-service.json and placed in app folder?
follow this example for reference : http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

when app is in background on messagerecieve class will not hitt so you have to hande from server at the time of making payload send payload similer to this.

```
{
    "to" : "zzzzz",
     "notification": {
     "body": "",
     "title": "",
    "icon": ""
},
"data" : {
 "name" : ""

}
  }
```